# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' in angular4

Tags: angular

I know there is a lot of forum which discusses on this issue, but my question is uniquely different.

My HTML for the component is like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let _policy of DynamicFormControls.controls ; let i=index" style="position: relative">
    <add-policy-details [policyGroup]="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls[i]"></add-policy-details>
    <div class="remove-btn" (click)="removePolicyTemplate(i)" *ngIf="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length > 1">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my `.ts` code is like this:

```
get DynamicFormControls() {
    return <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails');
}
```

When I try to compile the code using the command:

> ng build --target=production --environment=prod

I get an error like this:

[image]

I was referring [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15709) blog but had no help.

Comment: Don't use `controls` with aot. Prefer using `.get` method instead

Comment: do you mean to say that i have to use get.DynamicFormControls() in  the html? can you be a little more precise

Comment: `lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls[i]` should be like `lienHolder.get(['policyDetails', i]`

Comment: i tried it but i am getting the same error
  <add-policy-details [policyGroup]="lienHolder.get(['policyDetails', i])"></add-policy-details>

Comment: Remove all `controls`

Comment: i have made changes in the html like this
  <div formArrayName="policyDetails">
            <div *ngFor="let _policy of DynamicFormControls; let i=index" style="position: relative">
                   <add-policy-details [policyGroup]="lienHolder.get(['policyDetails', i])"></add-policy-details>
              <div class="remove-btn" (click)="removePolicyTemplate(i)" *ngIf="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length > 1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

Comment: and the .ts like this
get DynamicFormControls() {

    var dControls = <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails');
    return dControls['controls'];
  }
still i am getting the same error

Comment: I still see `controls` here `*ngIf="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length > 1`